# Import Data in Excel Column to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, import-from-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns; *job_number* and *referred_by*. I have a SQL Server table with the same two columns. Most of the Job Numbers from the excel spreadsheet exist in the SQL server but not all of them.

How would I import all the *referred_by* into the SQL Server where a matching *job_number* exists?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query an excel spreadsheet I would set it up as a linked server, so:

```
EXEC sp_addLinkedServer
    @server= 'xlsx_NewSheet',
    @srvproduct = 'ACE 12.0',
    @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    @datasrc = 'C:\spreadsheet.xlsx',
    @provstr = 'Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes'
```

With that set up you can almost query it like just another table:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (XLSX_NewSheet, 'Select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM XLSX_NewSheet...[Sheet1$]
```

There are some limitations that you may need to explore. I would suggest just dumping the entire contents into a temp table and operating from there.